# Firefox react fetch does not include cookie

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cookies, browser, fetch-api

I'm trying to implement Discord OAuth2 in my React app with Spring Boot REST API. How it should work:

1. In React app (`localhost on port1`) I manually set window.location.href to my backend application  oauth2 authorization endpoint. (`localhost port 2 /api/oauth2/authorization/discord`)

```
 async function onSubmit() {
        try {
            window.location.href =
              "http test.local port2/api/oauth2/authorization/discord";
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

2. GET request is sent to test.local, which responds with HTTP 302 to `https discordapp /oauth2/authorize?...` **along with** `Set-Cookie: ...` Http header (this is important)

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Set-Cookie: oauth2_auth_request=long_cookie_value; Path=/; Max-Age=180; Expires=Sun, 29 Jan 2023 14:13:47 GMT; SameSite=None
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: https discordapp com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=...&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5173/login
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 29 Jan 2023 14:10:47 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

3. User sees the discord login page
4. Now if I open `http test local port2` in the browser I can see that the cookie was set correctly
   [cookie screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWKw4.png)
5. User logs in to discord, discord redirects to `http localhost port1/login?code=...&state=...`
6. In react app I fetch `GET http test.local port2/api/login/oauth2/code/discord?code=...&state=...`
   Code:

```
    fetch(
      `http test local port2/api/login/oauth2/code/discord?code=${searchParams.get("code")}&state=${searchParams.get("state")}`,
      {
        credentials: "include",
      }
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
```

Request headers:

```
GET /api/login/oauth2/code/discord?code=...&state=... HTTP/1.1
Host: sss.test:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:5173/
Origin: http://localhost:5173
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

**Expected result:**

The request is sent together with the cookie set in step 2. (required to confirm that both requests in authorization flow are sent from the same origin)

**Actual result:**

Cookie is not set.

**Observations:**

- If I open `http test.local port2/api/login/oauth2/code/discord?code=...&state=...` in the browser, the cookie is set

Request headers:

```
GET /api/login/oauth2/code/discord?code=...&stat=... HTTP/1.1
Host: sss.test:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: oauth2_auth_request=long_cookie_value
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

- Works on the same domain for FE and BE

**Notes:**

- Using http for development purpose only. I will switch to https and BE available on external server soon, but in the meantime I want to make it work for http and local. BE and FE will be hosted on the same server with proxy for /api requests that will direct api requests to BE port. But I will need cross-origin cookie for local FE development with external BE API anyway.
- Chrome blocks non-secure, sameSite: none cookies, so it will not work there. Firefox allows it (for now), so I'm testing on firefox.
- Spring Security configuration:

```
...
                .cors()
                    .configurationSource(request -> {
                        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
                        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                        config.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:5173"));
                        return config;
                    })
...
```

- FE should receive JWT token in the response of this request for further authentication.
- Sorry for weird URLs sometimes but apparently this question is SPAM -.-